# Accessing static content from IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express, nancy

I'm working on a Nancy app which contains various folders from which I would like to access static content in my code. These folders are copied to my project's bin directory. Normally, accessing these would be simple using the default `RootPathProvider`.

However when I run the app in IIS Express, the root path is calculated to be something along the lines of

```
...AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\... (several more folders)
```

as this is the location from which the assembly is executing. However this location does not contain my whole project, just one assembly. IIS Express is splitting up the project's assemblies amongst several folders and I can't find my static content in these folders anywhere.

Is there a way to reference static content that is normally copied to the web app's bin folder when using IIS Express other than by using a hardcoded path?